# Microsoft.WebView2 & Edge

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, webview2, tedgebrowser

I'm trying to use Microsoft.WebView2 from microsoft.web.webview2.0.9.579.nupkg (TEdgeBrowser example from Delphi 10.4 Version 27.0.38860.1461)

This version works with **canary or beta** versions of Edge only. With release of Edge I got an error message **Could not find Edge installation. Do you have a version installed that's compatible with this WebView2 SDK version?**

[Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component) says about **canary** versions of Edge only.

Which version of Microsoft.WebView2 will work with Edge release ?

Comment: Why don't you try version `1.0.664.37` - the latest official release - and see if that works?

Comment: @PoulBak 
- microsoft.web.webview2.1.0.664.37.nupkg
- Edge release 87.0.664.60

error message: Could not find Edge installation. Do you have a version installed that's compatible with this WebView2 SDK version?

Answer (score 2):

I am not available with the **Delphi app** but I try to make a test with the **Windows Forms app**. In which, I download the **webView2 1.0.664.37** using **Nuget package manager** and I try to test it with the **MS Edge Version 87.0.664.60** (stable version at present).

Based on my test result, it did not work with the **MS Edge Version 87.0.664.60** (stable version at present).

So as per this test result, the **webView2 1.0.664.37** may not work in your Delphi app with the current stable version of the Edge browser (Version 87.0.664.60). You can test it in your Delphi app to verify it.

I make further tests and found that if I install the [webView2 Evergreen Standalone Installer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) then it is working on my side. You can notice that there is a minor difference in the version of the webView2 runtime and MS Edge stable browser.

[image]

So if you are available to use the webView2 runtime then you can make a test with it.

If you cannot use the webView2 runtime and webView2 1.0.664.37 also not working in your Delphi app then I suggest you keep using the MS Edge Canary or Dev version with the webView2.

Comment: Thanks for your test. 

I have to display some web pages inside my desktop app

I chose edge because it is a standard component of the operating system as it is now - an exporter

i must have an industrial solution

deploying e webView2 Evergreen IMHO is not a good idea

Comment: I tested with  webView2 Evergreen
Error message: Failed to initialise Edge browser control

Comment: WebView2 for .Net requires either WebView2 Runtime or the Canary build of Edge, not release builds of Edge!

Comment: @MarkLobanov, In that case, I suggest you keep using the MS Edge Canary version as mentioned in the official document. I suggest you refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#feedback) and try to provide feedback regarding webView2 by clicking on the `This Product` button under feedback options. Thanks for your understanding.